# Serialize object, preserve order of xs:group

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xsd, xml-serialization

I want to serialize an object using XmlSerializer and want it to use the order defined in a XSD.

For example I have an XSD with element like this:

```
...
<xs:element name="Screen" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Yaxis" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="ab:AxisType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...

<xs:complexType name="AxisType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="ab:IntervalSegmentGroup" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="LastPoint" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="ab:PointType" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="IntervalSegmentGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Point" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="ab:PointType"/>
    <xs:element name="Interpolation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="PointType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Relative" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="Absolute" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

I have then used XSD.exe to create stub-classes for this. 
Then I create objects from these claseses and populate them with data. And then I serialize them with an XMLSerializer.

The result I WANT to get is something like this:

```
...
<Yaxis>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0</Relative>
    <Absolute>0</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0.456</Relative>
    <Absolute>100</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0.645</Relative>
    <Absolute>342</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <LastPoint>
    <Relative>1</Relative>
    <Absolute>3920</Absolute>
  </LastPoint>
</Yaxis>
...
```

But what i get is:

```
...
<Yaxis>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0</Relative>
    <Absolute>0</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0.456</Relative>
    <Absolute>100</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Point>
    <Relative>0.645</Relative>
    <Absolute>342</Absolute>
  </Point>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation>
  <LastPoint>
    <Relative>1</Relative>
    <Absolute>3920</Absolute>
  </LastPoint>
</Yaxis>
...
```

When I try to validate the XML against the XSD it will fail, as it doesn't confirm to the order Point, Interpolation, Point...

What am I doing wrong? Can I control this in some kind of way?

Comment: Maybe the stub-classes created by `XSD.exe` is ordered like that. You might also post the resulting stub-classes, if you may, to help us in answering your question.

Comment: Is the <Interpolation>linear</Interpolation> related to your <Point>? Aren't you missing an additional level in your schema, then? My point is: isn't that "order" thing indicating that something is wrong with your actual schema and you should refactor it?

Answer (score 0):

Try While Generating the Classes you can specify the Order argument for XSD.exe.

XSD.exe.

/order
    Generate explicit order identifiers on all particle members.

May be this solve your issue.